# How do I convert .GDDII file to .geo file?

Tags: file, geometry, backend, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert GDDII files to .geo and I can't find any resources online. I'm willing to program a website to act as a converter but I am not sure what tools and libraries can be used to convert .GDDII to .geo

I appreciate any tips and suggestions, thank you.